# print data to twig file from custom form submit via controller

Tags: 8, theming, forms

I have created a custom form, and I'm passing data to twig file from `submitForm` function as follows

```
public function submitForm(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state)
{
$form_state->setRebuild();

$data = ['role' => $form_state->getValue('role'),
'date' => $form_state->getValue('date')
];
MyController::Detail($data);

}
```

and in controller passing data to twig

```
public static function Detail($data) {

return [
'#theme' => 'my_report',
'#data' => $data,
];

}
```

but not able to get/print data in twig file.

Answer (score 0):

When you set rebuild in a form submit there is no controller involved. The next page displayed is the rebuilt form, where you can print the my_report twig template by adding it to the build array `$form`.

You don't need to transfer the values in $form_state, because they are available while rebuilding the form. You can check in the form build function whether these values are present. If not, you are building a new form. If they are, this is a form rebuild, then display the result template:

```
  public function buildForm(array $form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {

    // build form

    if ($form_state->hasValue('role')) {
      $form['my_report'] = [
        '#theme' => 'my_report',
        '#role' => $form_state->getValue('role'),
      ];
    }
    return $form;
  }
```

Comment: did you mean to call twig template in submitForm function? because I need to pass submitted data to twig

Comment: No, I mean the form build function. I add a code example.

Comment: I have added `$form['#theme'] = 'my_report';` in build function but it gives empty form means without fields, my requirement is to pass submitted data to twig

Comment: Sorry, I can't help you any further, because we are not allowed to extend the topic in the comments. My answer is for `$form_state->setRebuild();`. You can also use `$form_state->setRedirect('route.to.controller');`. Search for similar questions. If you can't find anything helpful ask a new question.

Comment: I m able to resolve the issue